# Call method in OnDestroy dont works

Tags: android

I'm trying to call a service in my `OnDestroy ()`, but neither a log is working, does anyone know why?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("onDestroy", "here");
    startService(new Intent(this, ServiceOff.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If I call the service on the onStop, it runs, even if it is called when I close the app too, but it can not be called there because of the obvious reason that onStop can still open the app.

**Important, I'm closing the app by pulling the window mode and dragging the side**

Full code of activity:

```
public class editar_perfil extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton ok;
    TextInputEditText senha, new_senha;
    ProgressBar login_progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar_perfil);

        reference();
    }

    private void reference() {
        ok = findViewById(R.id.ok);
        senha = findViewById(R.id.senha);
        new_senha = findViewById(R.id.new_senha);
        login_progress = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

        ok.setOnClickListener(v ->{
            if(conectV(this)) {
                if (ge(senha).length() > 7 && ge(new_senha).length() > 7) {
                    String paramentros = "session=" + session +
                            "&id=" + meu_id +
                            "&senha=" + ge(senha) +
                            "&new_senha=" + ge(new_senha);

                    stateAll(false, senha, new_senha, ok);

                    showProgress(true, login_progress, this);
                    new SolicitaDados(paramentros).execute(url + "new_senha.php");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Tamanho de senha inválido!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sem conexão com a internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String parametros;

        private SolicitaDados(String paramentros) {
            this.parametros = paramentros;
            Log.e("script", paramentros);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], this.parametros);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
            if (resultado != null) {
                Log.e("res", resultado);
                if(resultado.contains("ok")){
                    Toast.makeText(editar_perfil.this, "Senha alterada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                }else{
                    stateAll(true, senha, new_senha, ok);
                    showProgress(false, login_progress, editar_perfil.this);
                    Toast.makeText(editar_perfil.this, "Senha antiga incorreta, tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                stateAll(true, senha, new_senha, ok);
                showProgress(false, login_progress, editar_perfil.this);
                Toast.makeText(editar_perfil.this, "Erro inesperado, tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("onDestroy", "here");
        startService(new Intent(this, ServiceOff.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: onDestroy of what? Activity? Fragment? If onDestroy is not getting called do you think it's the appropriate method for your use case?

Comment: I didn't get your point.

Comment: is the onDetroy-Method called at all?

Comment: onDestroy() will be called only when your activity is killed. Is that happening?

Comment: Yeah, he called, im closing the app, and its a activity

Comment: closing the app is not guaranteed to finish or destroy your activity, it might just be paused, check out the activity lifecycle for more info https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: I see in logcat, and the app is died, then he called, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps to you need to follow:

Step 1: Create a new class and extend it with BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class Reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Added a toast just to check but you can also add startService() here
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Step 2: Register the receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Reciever"
          android:process=":remote" />  // This is important
```

Step 3: Then in your main activity register a alarm manager:

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            Reciever.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
            0, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    assert manager != null;
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            60000L /*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR*/,  pendingIntent);
```

Step 4: Swipe your app to kill and after sometime you will see the alarm manager will fire your onRecieve() method.

You need to keep a watch on your device to see if it's working.

See if it works and update me please.

Comment: I find another way, I'll post here.

Answer (score 2):

From [onDestroy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) docs:

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Probably your activity is still existing, that's why onDestroy is not called.

I don't know whole code, so it's hard to tell what you want to achieve, maybe onPause() or onStop() will do the trick.

Comment: I see the logcat, and the app is died

Comment: Is App died then it's to late to start Activity. If you want to have code running after app is killed, maybe use Services?
What do you want to achieve, because your question is missing details.

Comment: In on destroy I call a service to send a request to my server saying that the connection between them is over

Comment: If I call onStop, when I close the app, it calls service, the problem is that n can be in it because onStop is called other times

Comment: Idea: create binded service; when your activity will be destroyed, service will detects unbinding but you still should be able to send info to your server before service will be finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("onDestroy", "here");
    startService(new Intent(context, ServiceOff.class));
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Yeah, if I call it in onStop works, even if it's called when I close the app too

Comment: @WotonSampaio The only way I see is, use a broadcast receiver in onDestroy() then in onRecieve() method start your service.. don't forget to register the receiver in the manifest.. try if it works..

Comment: But neither the log is being called, how will it call the broadcast?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } I just checked this in my laptop, and I got a "Hi" .. It's wierd why you are not seeing a log.. Add a toast message and check..

Comment: Do you want all the code in my class? I find it unnecessary, it is very large

Comment: Yes please.. At the end of the day we need to get this done, so please do the needful.. may be I'll be able to help you..

Comment: I'll analyse, and update if I see any suspicious thing.. Thanks for adding the code.

Comment: @WotonSampaio Sorry to say this but from the docs: "Swiping the app from the task list basically means "kill this app right now" it's not given any time to perform an onDestroy. None of the lifecycle methods will be called."

Comment: Thank you ... Wow, it's gone now, I'll have to find another alternative

Comment: Bro, What is your requirement basically?

Comment: When the application closes, it calls this service that sends a request to my server warning that the user is off

Comment: You can call the service from onDestroy() if you finish the app or press back button to close it.. But if you swipe to kill then you need to use a receiver to call onReceive() ... Unfortunately I don't have the code right now to do that.. I'll post a new answer regarding that after few hours.. It's bin my office laptop ... But don't worry I'll help you as much as possible..

Comment: Yeah.. :) sure.